# Problems migrating to Spring boot 2 with CXF and Apache Camel

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, cxf

In my project we were working with Spring Boot 1.5.7, Apache Camel 2.19.3 and Apache CXF 3.2.1 and we had no problems with SOAP services. But when migrating to Spring Boot 2.1.3 with Apache Camel 2.24.1 and Apache CXF 3.3.2, the SOAP services have stopped working.

I hope that when invoking the SOAP services, the answers are correct, as before the migration. However, the error that is currently coming to me is as follows.

```
[                          main] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Total 23 routes, of which 23 are started
[                          main] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Apache Camel 2.24.1 (CamelContext: mainContextCamel) started in 6.011 seconds
[                          main] InitApplication                INFO  Started InitApplication in 17.779 seconds (JVM running for 30.23)
[               qtp83182348-187] input                          INFO  Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: null, Body: [Body is null]]
[               qtp83182348-182] PhaseInterceptorChain          WARN  Interceptor for {http://adaptation.ws.iacm.indra.com}adaptationService#{http://adaptation.ws.iacm.indra.com}getDefaultStep has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: null
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WrapperClassOutInterceptor.handleMessage(WrapperClassOutInterceptor.java:107) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:90) [cxf-core-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.resume(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:278) [cxf-core-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:78) [cxf-core-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:247) [cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:79) [cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) [jetty-server-9.4.14.v20181114.jar:9.4.14.v20181114]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257) [jetty-server-9.4.14.v20181114.jar:9.4.14.v20181114]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345) [jetty-server-9.4.14.v20181114.jar:9.4.14.v20181114]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:205) [jetty-server-9.4.14.v20181114.jar:9.4.14.v20181114]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247) [jetty-server-9.4.14.v20181114.jar:9.4.14.v20181114]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144) [jetty-server-9.4.14.v20181114.jar:9.4.14.v20181114]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:194) [jetty-server-9.4.14.v20181114.jar:9.4.14.v20181114]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) [jetty-server-9.4.14.v20181114.jar:9.4.14.v20181114]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handleAsync(Server.java:547) [jetty-server-9.4.14.v20181114.jar:9.4.14.v20181114]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:388) [jetty-server-9.4.14.v20181114.jar:9.4.14.v20181114]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.run(HttpChannel.java:305) [jetty-server-9.4.14.v20181114.jar:9.4.14.v20181114]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765) [jetty-util-9.4.14.v20181114.jar:9.4.14.v20181114]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683) [jetty-util-9.4.14.v20181114.jar:9.4.14.v20181114]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.indra.iacm.adm.adp.jaxws_asm.GetDefaultStepResponse_WrapperTypeHelper1.createWrapperObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WrapperClassOutInterceptor.handleMessage(WrapperClassOutInterceptor.java:91) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: Try to look in your own source code at that point where you get the NPE in `m.indra.iacm.adm.adp.jaxws_asm.GetDefaultStepResponse_WrapperTypeHelper1.createWrapperObject`, for example by debugging or adding logging output etc

Comment: At the time among the many tests I did was to debug your code. I found that the obs comes to null. Object o2 = helper.createWrapperObject(objs);

Comment: Debugging I have seen an important difference. Before migrating from version, when I was making the SOAP call, I first went through my service and then through the WrapperClassOutInterceptor interceptor.
However, after migrating the SOAP call, it never reaches my service. And the interceptor gives me NPE because the response of the service is null.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this nullpointer error come from your server side of your cxf service so you should look in the back side of service.

Comment: The problem is that this interceptor jumps before calling my service. Which did not happen before the migration.